# PDO Exception errors

Tags: php

Can someone help me whit these errors ?

[image]

My table is like this in my database :

[image]

Here is my code :

```
<?php
  $bdd=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cmadatabase','root','@Rugby3390', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
  $reponse= $bdd->query('SELECT IR,Level,Type,ToBeAnalyzed,Supplier,
                                Consequences,Remarks,SUM(Level,Type,Supplier) AS sommeLvlTypeSup 
                            FROM andgate 
                            GROUP BY IR,Level,Type,ToBeAnalyzed,
                                    Supplier,Consequences,Remarks 
                            ORDER BY SUM(Level,Type,Supplier) ASC');
  while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch()) {
    echo '<p>'.$donnees['IR'].','.$donnees['Level'].','.
        $donnees['Type'].','.$donnees['ToBeAnalyzed'].','.
        $donnees['Supplier'].','.$donnees['Consequences'].','.
        $donnees['Remarks'].','.$donnees['sommeLvlTypeSup'].'<p>';
  }
?>
```

Thank you a lot

Comment: Make try catch block around query or fetch and check what exact error is

Comment: able to use alias name in order by clause ORDER BY sommeLvlTypeSup  ASC

Comment: still not working but thx though

Comment: did you tried try catch block ?

Comment: I 'am actually looking for how to use try catch block, i didn't know about it

Comment: try {
 
 //$bdd
 //.......  push ur all code herer 
 //echo ...
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

Comment: Thx for the information, so my errors is : Connection failed: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 Erreur de syntaxe pr�s de 'Type,Supplier) AS sommeLvlTypeSup FROM andgate GROUP BY IR,Level,Type,ToBeAnalyz' � la ligne 1      now i am looking for my syntax error but was sure to have veryfied well this

Comment: i think type is keyword of mysql . give a try on my answer @PaulAlex

Comment: _If you can read it, just maybe you can debug it!!!_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Level, Type these are MySQL reserved keywords. You need to enclosed them properly

```
    <?php
try{
      $bdd=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cmadatabase','root','@Rugby3390', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
        $reponse= $bdd->query('SELECT `IR`,`Level`,`Type`,`ToBeAnalyzed`,`Supplier`,`Consequences`,`Remarks`,SUM(`Level`,`Type`,`Supplier`) AS sommeLvlTypeSup FROM andgate GROUP BY `IR`,`Level`,`Type`,`ToBeAnalyzed`,`Supplier`,`Consequences`,`Remarks` ORDER BY SUM(`Level`,`Type`,`Supplier`) ASC');
    while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
    {
        echo '<p>'.$donnees['IR'].','.$donnees['Level'].','.$donnees['Type'].','.$donnees['ToBeAnalyzed'].','.$donnees['Supplier'].','.$donnees['Consequences'].','.$donnees['Remarks'].','.$donnees['sommeLvlTypeSup'].'<p>';
    }
} catch(PDOExpection $px) {
    echo $px->getMessage();
}
    ?>
```

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Answer (score 0):

**1st :** Alias name in `order by` clause `ORDER BY sommeLvlTypeSup ASC`

**2nd :** `Type` is `mysql keyword` . so try to `enclose` the `backticks` around `table name`  `column` name

```
try
{
    $bdd=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cmadatabase','root','@Rugby3390');
    $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $reponse= $bdd->query('SELECT `IR`,`Level`,`Type`,`ToBeAnalyzed`,
                                    `Supplier`,`Consequences`,`Remarks`,
                                    SUM(`Level`,`Type`,`Supplier`) AS sommeLvlTypeSup 
                            FROM `andgate` 
                            GROUP BY `IR`,`Level`,`Type`,`ToBeAnalyzed`,
                                     `Supplier`,`Consequences`,`Remarks` 
                            ORDER BY sommeLvlTypeSup  ASC');
    while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch()){
        echo '<p>'.$donnees['IR'].','.$donnees['Level'].','.$donnees['Type'].','.$donnees['ToBeAnalyzed'].','.$donnees['Supplier'].','.$donnees['Consequences'].','.$donnees['Remarks'].','.$donnees['sommeLvlTypeSup'].'<p>';
      }
}

catch (PDOException $e) { echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();}
```

Comment: Hum, getting the same error whis this code, thank you though maybe i should change my column name in phpmyadmin ?

Comment: error is in other language . we can't read it . can you translate it to english @PaulAlex

Comment: :), yeah actually just saying there is a syntax error, nothing more, but yeah maybe Type is a keyword in mysql, so it s the problem