# Syntax error, query sql

Tags: php, sql

Here is my code :

```
try
{
    $bdd=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cmadatabase','root','@Rugby3390');
    $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $reponse= $bdd->query('SELECT IR,Level,Type,ToBeAnalyzed,
                                    Supplier,Consequences,Remarks,
                                    SUM(Level,Type,Supplier) AS sommeLvlTypeSup 
                            FROM andgate 
                            GROUP BY IR,Level,Type,ToBeAnalyzed,
                                     Supplier,Consequences,Remarks 
                            ORDER BY SUM(Level,Type,Supplier) ASC');
    while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch()){
        echo '<p>'.$donnees['IR'].','.$donnees['Level'].','.$donnees['Type'].','.$donnees['ToBeAnalyzed'].','.$donnees['Supplier'].','.$donnees['Consequences'].','.$donnees['Remarks'].','.$donnees['sommeLvlTypeSup'].'<p>';
      }
}

catch (PDOException $e) { echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();}

?>
```

Here is my error :

> Connection failed: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 Erreur de syntaxe pr�s de 'Type,Supplier) AS sommeLvlTypeSup FROM andgate GROUP BY IR,Level,Type,ToBeAnalyz' � la ligne 1

Could you help ? I am not seing where my syntax error is ?

Thx a lot

Comment: `SUM(Level,Type,Supplier)` - what makes you think SUM could be used that way, or that that would even make any sense?

Comment: Please Don't spam the SO . try to edit your old post . instead of posting new question  . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45007553/pdo-exeption-errors    I'm voting to close this question

Comment: If you can read it, there is just a chance you might be able to debug it!!!!

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
"ORDER BY SUM(Level,Type,Supplier)"
```

to

```
"ORDER BY sommeLvlTypeSup"
```

In theory, GROUP/ORDER BY SUM(..) not work.

Answer (score 0):

try  `ORDER BY sommeLvlTypeSup` instead of `SUM(Level,Type,Supplier)`